# Redirect to /en if page not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have in codeigniter a web with several languages. All is ok, for example https://example.com/en/mydetails.html

But if I use https://example.com/mydetails.html I get error. I don't know if I have to change .htaccess or in routes.php file.

My routes.php file have:

```
    $route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = 'notfound';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = true;

$route['^es$'] = $route['default_controller'];
$route['^en$'] = $route['default_controller'];
$route['^fr$'] = $route['default_controller'];
$prepended_lang = "(?:[a-zA-Z]{2}/)?";
```

And my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|aplication|admin|css|js|img\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
```

Thanks

the error I see ishere: https://monosnap.com/file/h2ubaFmjznLB96RSEEI1IplM69jwTK

Comment: add `RewriteBase /your_project_root/` to your .htaccess

Comment: It does not work for me

Comment: what did you add for that line?

Answer (score 0):

Thats my CI routes config end, maybe can help you:

```
//more than 2 chars on start uri segment
$route['^(\w{3,})\/?(:any)'] = '$1/$2';
//2 chars lang + /uri_segment
$route['^(\w{2})\/?(:any)'] = '$2';
//only 2 chars
$route['^(\w{2})$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

There is a lot of CI version, in my case, CI 2.x working with HMVC, MX Controllers, etc etc

CI 3 has some way to work with regular expresions: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html?highlight=routes#regular-expressions

Maybe can work something like this, not tested:

```
//more than 2 chars on start uri segment
$route['^([a-zA-Z]{3,})/(:any)'] = '$1/$2';
//2 chars lang + /uri_segment
$route['^([a-zA-Z]{2})/(:any)'] = '$2';
//only 2 chars
$route['^([a-zA-Z]{2})'] = $route['default_controller'];
```